# enable "pass special keys directly to VNC server" by default

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

I want to enable ALT-TAB in my VNCs by default, rather than clicking the top-left icon of the window, then `properties`, then clicking the checkbox for `pass special keys directly to VNC server` for every VNC window I open, every time I open one.

Using `RealVNC` viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the location of the VNC viewer executable:

  - `C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer`
- double-click

  - `vncviewer.exe`
- click

  - `File`
- then in the drop-down menu, click

  - `Preferences`
- in the pop-up window, click

  - `Expert`
- filter the list with

  - `SendSpecialKeys`
- click the parameter `SendSpecialKeys`
- click the `Value` drop-down
- then select `True`
- click `OK`